# Conditional Where?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

Using the following table. I am trying to get the Party_ID.
I will have just the NEW_ORG_ID and ORIGINAL_ID.

Using the NEW_ORG_ID I want to get the PARTY_ID with the MAX(USR_CRTE_TS) **unless** the ORIGINAL_ID matches as well. Then I want the PARTY_ID where the NEW_ORG_ID and ORIGINAL_ID match.

```
PARTY_ID          |DIRS_ID  |SUPPLIER_ID|ORIGINAL_ID|TRIANGLE_ID|NEW_ORG_ID|USR_CRTE_TS        |
------------------|---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|----------|-------------------|
5385606962        |476800490|5385606962 |NULL       |NULL       |69214683  |2018-09-27 04:56:13|
69214683          |476800490|NULL       |2740793553 |NULL       |69214683  |2018-09-27 04:54:15|
```

I tried the following. Keep in mind I hardcoded the NEW_ORG_ID and ORIGINAL_ID for this example only. In the real world example NEW_ORG_ID and ORIGINAL_ID are supplied by another part of the query.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT PARTY_ID 
FROM UNIQUE_IDS UNQ 
WHERE   
( 
        CASE
            WHEN ( 
                    SELECT ts.PARTY_ID
                    FROM UNIQUE_IDS ts 
                    WHERE (ts.NEW_ORG_ID = '69214683' AND ts.ORIGINAL_ID = '2740793553') 
                 ) IS NOT NULL
            THEN 
                (
                    SELECT ts.PARTY_ID 
                    FROM UNIQUE_IDS ts 
                    WHERE (ts.NEW_ORG_ID = '69214683' AND ts.ORIGINAL_ID = '2740793553') 
                )
            ELSE 
                (
                    SELECT ts.PARTY_ID
                    FROM UNIQUE_IDS ts 
                    WHERE ts.NEW_ORG_ID = '69214683'
                    AND ts.USR_CRTE_TS = (  
                                            SELECT MAX(ts.USR_CRTE_TS) 
                                            FROM UNIQUE_IDS ts 
                                            WHERE ts.NEW_ORG_ID = '69214683'
                                        )--xref.SBL_GLOB_CSTMR_ID)
                )
        END
) = UNQ.NEW_ORG_ID
```

;

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you on?

Comment: Oracle Version 11.2.0.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to get the "best" match (first by `ORIGINAL_ID`, and then by `USR_CRTE_TS`) marked with number 1, and filter on that:

```
SELECT PARTY_ID
FROM   (
            SELECT  PARTY_ID,
                    USR_CRTE_TS,  
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY PARTY_ID 
                        ORDER BY     CASE ORIGINAL_ID 
                                         WHEN '2740793553' THEN 0 
                                         ELSE 1 
                                     END,
                                     USR_CRTE_TS DESC
                    ) RN
            FROM    UNIQUE_IDS
            WHERE   NEW_ORG_ID = '69214683'
        )
WHERE   RN = 1
```

If `USR_CRTE_TS` can be `NULL`, then add another condition at the very end to be in line with what you had:

```
AND     (ORIGINAL_ID = '2740793553' OR USR_CRTE_TS IS NOT NULL)
```

#### When the criteria are selected elsewhere

You can use the `WITH` clause to build up your query, layer by layer.
So let's assume you already have working logic to select the two "parameters", then put that in a `with` clause like this:

```
WITH CRIT(SEL_ORG_ID, SEL_ORIGINAL_ID) AS (
    SELECT '69214683', '2740793553' FROM DUAL -- this is just an example
)
```

... and then continue the query like this:

```
), BASE AS (
    SELECT  UI.PARTY_ID,
            UI.USR_CRTE_TS,
            UI.ORIGINAL_ID,
            CRIT.SEL_ORIGINAL_ID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY UI.PARTY_ID 
                ORDER BY     CASE UI.ORIGINAL_ID 
                                 WHEN CRIT.SEL_ORIGINAL_ID THEN 0 
                                 ELSE 1 
                             END,
                             UI.USR_CRTE_TS DESC
            ) RN
    FROM    UNIQUE_IDS UI,
            CRIT
    WHERE   UI.NEW_ORG_ID = CRIT.SEL_NEW_ORG_ID
)
SELECT PARTY_ID
FROM   BASE
WHERE  RN = 1
AND    (ORIGINAL_ID = SEL_ORIGINAL_ID OR USR_CRTE_TS IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have a scoping issue where NEW_ORG_ID = xref.SBL_GLOB_CSTMR_ID (replaces the hardcoded. '69214683') I get the error SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "XREF"."SBL_GLOB_CSTMR_ID": invalid identifier

  ORA-00904: "XREF"."SBL_GLOB_CSTMR_ID": invalid identifier

  ORA-00904: "XREF"."SBL_GLOB_CSTMR_ID": invalid identifier

I assume that is a scoping issue. Where my outer query's table and field can't be "seen" inside the subquery.

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `row_number()` with conditional ordering:

```
select party_id 
  from (
    select party_id, 
           row_number() over (order by case when original_id = '2740793553' then 1 end, 
                                       usr_crte_ts desc) rn
      from unique_ids unq
      where new_org_id = '69214683')
  where rn = 1
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c239d41f96419639d09ca50919df6ffe)</sup>**

If `original_id` matches then row has higher priority. Second priority is highest `usr_crte_ts`. Finally we take first best row.